# How to synthesize and isolate single stranded cDNA from an RNA template?

Tags: molecular-biology, biotechnology, nucleic-acids

I would like to have pure single stranded cDNA of my choice. I am thinking of reverse transcription from RNA (obtained by in vitro transcription), degrading RNA from RNA-DNA hybrid with RNase-H, heating to 65C to remove any oligoribonucleotides still bound to DNA and pass the solution through G50 sephadex column buffered with elution buffer. This is what I have in mind but are there any efficient ways that are tried before? Or do you have any suggestions over this protocol?

Comment: You need a DNA template to do in vitro transcription, so I'm not really understanding what you want to do here? How long is your sequence?

Comment: You need to use reverse transcriptase and a thermal cycler. Not much more to it, follow manufacturers suggestions. Life tech makes good RT

Comment: @MadScientist I think he's talking about rna->cDNA here not invitro Txn.

Answer (score 3):

Sure that will work, or gel purify the ss cDNA, or treat the rxn with alkali to degrade RNA.  The real questions in my mind are:

1. What will you use as a primer for the RT?
2. What are you going to do with this pure ss cDNA?

If you already have the target cloned (how else would you transcribe it *in vitro*?), then why not just do a linear PCR where you cut the plasmid to linearize it at the site of your choosing, and then throw it in a PCR machine with just one primer?

Why bother going through the T7 RNA pol and RT steps (if you don't need to)?